# htaccess redirect url to parent directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I am getting an issue on my website. Google indexes many this kind of  URLs:

`http://example.com/folder/url1.php/url2.php`

So, how can I redirect to my original URL, which in this case is:

`http://example.com/folder/url1.php`

There is another folder2 also in folder and only redirect if there is another url appended after url1.php

Frankly speaking, I am really new to this *htaccess* redirect, I never used this before.
So, any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectMatch` directive to redirect your URLs.

At the top of your htaccess file, add the following line :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.php$ https://example.com/folder/$1
```

To redirect a particular/single URI , you can use

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/file.php/file.php$ https://example.com/folder/file.php
```

Comment: Thanks for a lot for the solution and what if wanted to redirect to just 404 not found because the whole url is not valid.

And if we open the url like this http://example.com/http://example.com it still open rather than throwing 404 error

Comment: This method is not working i use the first code and place the code by changing the folder to my folder name. But it did not work no redirection work

Comment: I have another folder which is folder 2 under folder which is also redirecting to 301 how to prevent this and only redirect if any new url or folder is appended to .php file